# reason of the error message "...cannot be resolved..."

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat

I start learning jsp application, and sometimes i got the error message "something cannot be resolved...". For example, this is my last report:

```
An error occurred at line: 118 in the jsp file: /functions.jsp
session cannot be resolved
115:             
116:     Boolean isLogged()
117:         {
118:             Boolean loginSuccess = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("myApp.loginSuccess");
119:             if (loginSuccess == null) 
120:             {
121:                 return false;
```

These lines refer to a function, that checks the success of the login procedure. So i have two questions:

1. How can i fix the problem in this situation?
2. What's the reason of these messages, that sometimes disappears with no cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the returned value of `getAttribute()` method.

```
Boolean loginSuccess = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("myApp.loginSuccess");
```

You can't use `implicit` object variables directly into method body (declaration). You should have to [avoid Java code in JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) (Declaration, Scriptlet and Expression). Alternatively you can use use [Servlet/Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp).

To fix this issue declare a reference variable of `HttpSession` in declaration block.

```
<%!
  HttpSession sess;

  Boolean isLogged(){
     Boolean loginSuccess = (Boolean)sess.getAttribute("myApp.loginSuccess");
     if (loginSuccess == null) 
        ...
  }
%>
```

and assign the reference of `session` object to `sess` variable before you call the `isLogged` method.

e.g

```
<%
 sess=session;
 if(isLogged()){
   //code
 }
%>
```

Comment: Thanks, but anyway i get the same problem.